# LaTeX table cell coloring based on values in the cell (3 color scale formatting)

Tags: tables, color, gradient, cellcolor

I wanted to imitate the functionality in excel of 3-Scale grading formatting, which changes the background of a table cell based on its value.

I wanted each cell to have a percentage value, and each cell to gradually change from red to green depending on how close they are of 50%. The picture below shows the coloring I want:

[image]

I tried using the code from the article published by [Siavoosh](https://www.siavoosh.com/blog/2019/01/05/latex-table-cell-coloring-based-on-values-in-the-cell/),  however, this color scale is only 2-Color based. I have tried to rewrite his code so to have a 3-Scale:

```
% Color set related!
\definecolor{high}{rgb}{0.8500, 0.3250, 0.0980}  % the color for the highest number in your data set (Matlab Red)
\definecolor{middle}{rgb}{0.4660, 0.6740, 0.1880}  % the color for the highest number in your data set (Matlab Green)
\definecolor{low}{rgb}{0.8500, 0.3250, 0.0980}  % the color for the lowest number in your data set  (Matlab Red)
\newcommand*{\opacity}{100}% here you can change the opacity of the background color!

%======================================
% Data set related!
\newcommand*{\minval}{40.0}% define the minimum value on your data set
\newcommand*{\midval}{50.0}% define the middle value on your data set
\newcommand*{\maxval}{60.0}% define the maximum value in your data set!

%======================================
% gradient function single cell! 
\newcommand{\gradient}[1]{
\pgfmathparse{3*(round(100*(#1/(\maxval-\minval))-(\minval*(100/(\maxval-\minval)))))}
% \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(\maxval-\minval))-(\minval*(100/(\maxval-\minval)))))}
\xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}

% The values are calculated linearly between \minval and \maxval
\ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\maxval pt}{\cellcolor{high!\opacity} #1}{
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{\minval pt}{\cellcolor{high!\opacity} #1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\midval pt}{\cellcolor{high!\opacity} #1}{
            \cellcolor{middle!\tempa!low!\opacity} #1
        }}}}
```

However, for a reason I do not understand, when altering the  condition of the last `\ifdimcomp{<dimA>}{<relation>}{<dimB>}{<true>}{<false>}` my table does not work.

Does anyone how to fix it? Or an easier way to have a 3-scale for a table?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: (also show your attempt to modify the code.)